# Java code to show action on x amount of presses?

Tags: java, android, random

I have an iOS app that I worked on some time ago, and the function it uses I like, and would like to somehow get it to work on some Android code I have.

At the top of my `MainActivity` I have

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "nShownLobby";
```

on my `onCreate` I have

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And I am calling this method

```
changeTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        long nb_shown_lobby = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).getLong("nShownLobby", 0); 
        ++nb_shown_lobby; 
        if ((nb_shown_lobby % 20) == 0) { 
            this.turnAround(); 
        }
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * manyDifferentStrings.length);
        if (random == oldVaue) {
            random = (int) (Math.random() * manyDifferentStrings.length);
        }
        changingText.setText(manyDifferentStrings[random]);
        oldVaue = random;
        try {
            mySound.start();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            mySound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
        }
    }

    private void turnAround() {
        //Do something here
        Log.i("Do Something ", "");
    }
});
```

The intention is that after every 20 presses, the `turnAround()` method is called but it does not... It just gets ignored - I am guessing I have missed something?

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: Yes, the `turnAround` does not get called in debugging

Comment: you never save the value to sharedpreferences, only read, which will be 0 every time on every click therefore

Comment: @IvoBeckers I am used to iOS, whereabouts can I add the value to save?

Comment: @DannyRoy if it doesn't run, how do you expect it to be executed?

Comment: I'd suggest you to read the documentation about sharedpreferences https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: Thank you, I had not seen that small - but crucial detail! Still getting my head around java but appreciate it thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**According to your question your code should be like this**

private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private static final String MyPREFERENCES = "nShownLobby";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    changeTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){


            int nb_shown_lobby = sharedpreferences.getInt("nShownLobby", 0);
            if ((nb_shown_lobby % 20) == 0) {
                turnAround();
            }

            nb_shown_lobby += 1;
            editor.putInt("nShownLobby", nb_shown_lobby);
            editor.commit();

            int random = (int) (Math.random() * manyDifferentStrings.length);
            if (random == oldVaue) {
                random = (int) (Math.random() * manyDifferentStrings.length);
            }
            changingText.setText(manyDifferentStrings[random]);
            oldVaue = random;

            try {
                mySound.start();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                mySound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);

            }

        }

    });


}

//created this in activity, not in the button onclick
private void turnAround() {

    //Do something here
    Log.i("Do Something ", "");
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly - answer marked! Thank you